# what is the default path if I don't set "--base-path"

Tags: substrate-node-template

when I run substrate-node-template, some command use "--base-path" to specify custom base path. However, I want to know what is the default path if I don't set "--base-path". Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Different OS has different default path.

For linux, it is `$HOME/.local/share/<CHAIN_NAME>`.

---

Also, when you run the chain, it will show:

```
2023-03-16 00:33:24  Database: RocksDb at /xxx/db/full
```

`/xxx` is what you are looking for.